# my mongod is not working its keep giving me error in hyper terminal

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

[image: error I am getting in hyper terminal]

My mongod is not working. It keeps giving me error in hyper terminal like this:

```
_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 12, snapshot max: 12 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 
251"}}
```

Comment: Can you add the snippet of the code here as a text, not as an image? Also, you need to make your question reproducible, i.e. provide steps needed to reproduce this problem, ideally on a fresh MongoDB local instance, or provide more context to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem. It is just showing that mongo db is running in the background. I was thinking the same that it is an error, but it was not. You cannot edit in this prompt, just open new tab by Ctrl+Shift+T. Type mongo and hit enter there, you would see `>`, means you are ready to use Mongo shell, and can enter your mongo commands like show dbs etc.